# How to determine parameter W in butter function (bandpass filter) from signal package R?

Tags: r, signal-processing, butterworth, bandpass-filter

I would like to preprocess my collected data with a bandpass filter between

- 0.1 and 10 HZ and
- 0.01 and 10Hz.

  butter(n, W, type = c( "pass"))

According to the signal package documentation the parameter W must be between 0 and 1.

W : critical frequencies of the filter. W must be a scalar for low-pass and high-pass
filters, and W must be a two-element vector c(low, high) specifying the lower
and upper bands. For digital filters, W must be between 0 and 1 where 1 is the
Nyquist frequency

How do I determine W correctly according to this definition ?

Thanks!

I tried to calculate the Nyquist frequency

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).